# Why do I get this error - "missing token"? (playing with an API using Python)

Tags: python, api

So, I am playing around with [Etilbudsavis' API](http://docs.api.etilbudsavis.dk/docs/offer-search) (Danish directory containing offers from retail stores). **My goal is to retrieve data based on a search query**.  [the API acutally allows this](http://docs.api.etilbudsavis.dk/docs/offer-search), out of the box. However, when I try to do this, I end up with an error saying that my token is missing. Anyways, here is my code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from json import load
import requests

body = {'api_key': 'secret_api_key'}

response = requests.post('https://api.etilbudsavis.dk/v2/sessions', data=body)

print response.text

new_body = {'_token:': 'token_obtained_from_POST_method', 'query:': 'coca-cola'}

new_response = requests.get('https://api.etilbudsavis.dk/v2/offers/search', data=new_body)

print new_response.text
```

Full error:

```
{"code":1107,"id":"00ilpgq7etum2ksrh4nr6y1jlu5ng8cj","message":"missing token","
details":"Missing token\nNo token found in request to an endpoint that requires
a valid token.","previous":null,"@note.1":"Hey! It looks like you found an error
. If you have any questions about this error, feel free to contact support with
the above error id."}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a GET request, you should use the `params` argument to pass the data in the URL.

```
new_response = requests.get('https://api.etilbudsavis.dk/v2/offers/search', params=new_body)
```

See [the requests docs](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Comment: Now, I am getting a new error: `{"code":1106,"id":"00ilpnqbe2jeoxcnyejlh75vaho2c3jq","message":"No Origin","deta
ils":"Missing origin header\nThis token can not be used without a valid Origin h
eader.","previous":null,"@note.1":"Hey! It looks like you found an error. If you
 have any questions about this error, feel free to contact support with the abov
e error id."}`

Comment: Looks like you need to sign the token before you can use it, see [their docs](http://docs.api.etilbudsavis.dk/docs/getting-started#api-session-signatures).

Comment: It says: "If your eTilbudsavis app isn't executed by javascript in a browser, you need to sign your token, before you can start sending requests. Do not simply add an Origin header!". I am not writing a mobile app or anything like that. I should be okay without signing...

Comment: What? You're clearly executing the code from Python. So surely you *do* need to sign the token, because you're not doing it from JS in a browser.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the docs. Problem is solved now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with the help of Daniel Roseman who reminded me of the fact that playing with an API in the Python Shell is different from interacting with the API in the browser. The docs clearly stated that you'd have to sign the API token in order for it to work. I missed that tiny detail ... Never the less, Daniel helped me figure everything out. Thanks again, Dan.